# Actionscript add strings to embedded images?

Tags: actionscript-3

Say I have something like this:

```
[Embed(source='../lib/images/image01.png')] var Image:Class
```

But I want to change that images based on another string like so:`

```
var StringData:String
StringData = "02";
[Embed(source='../lib/images/image'+ StringData +'.png')] var Image:Class
```

But this gives me an error, is there another way to do something like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Embedded resources are evaluated at compiling time so you can't set a dynamic path.

If you want a unique path by compile type (debug / release for exemple), you can use compiler variables :

```
[Embed(source=CONFIG::ICON_PATH)]
var Image:Class;
```

And add compiler args:

```
-define+=CONFIG::ICON_PATH,'../lib/images/image01.png'
```

or

```
-define+=CONFIG::ICON_PATH,'../lib/images/image02.png'
```