# AS3 embed question

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3

I'm creating a wrapper SWF that needs to embed multiple swf's using the [Embed ] tag in Actionscript 3.

How can i embed a custom swf when compiling a as3 project using the flex sdk, E.G:

```
[Embed(source="/MySWF1.swf", mimeType="application/octet-stream")]
```

However i want to specify the 'source' location at compile time.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use compiler variable : [Actionscript add strings to embedded images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973145/actionscript-add-strings-to-embedded-images/5974580#5974580)